# There is no application installed for executable files

Tags: executable, unetbootin

I'm  a new Linux user. I bought 1 month ago a 64x Laptop with Windows 8 pre-installed.

Using UnetBootin I installed Ubuntu 12.10 and completely removed Windows 8.

Now, the new Ubuntu version is a bit too heavy for my slow laptop, I therefor decided to try Bodhi or Fedora. Like I did for installing Ubuntu, I downloaded UnetBootin for Linux, and the Bodhi image. I thought I could simply run UnetBootin and follow the same steps as I did on Windows, and then install Bodhi...

But as I double click the downloaded UnetBootin executable ["unetbootin-linux-583"] it gives me the following error:

```
Could not display "/home/laptop/Desktop/unetbootin-linux-583".
There is no application installed for executable files.
Do you want to search for an application to open this file?
```

I searched before about the error, and found several times the tip to change the `Allow executing file as a program` in the properties. I tried, and now if I double click, nothing happens at all.

Comment: Is this a question about ubuntu or about bodhi? If it is about bodhi then it is off-topic.

Comment: @Private, he's trying to run unetbootin on Ubuntu. It's not off-topic.

Comment: try opening a terminal window and type ./home/PATH/TO/EXECUTABLE. You can also try to make the bootable usb drive with ' start-up disk creator' it's already installed in ubuntu

Comment: Open the teminal, drag the the executable file into it and press enter

Comment: @EricCarvalho OK

Answer (score 15):

You have probably forgotten to make the unetbootin file executable.

Right click on `unetbootin-linux-583`, click on *Properties*, choose the tab *Permissions*. Check the small square *Allow executing file as program*.

Now double click unetbootin-linux-583 and fill in your password.

You can also do it through the command line. Open a **Terminal** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
cd /path/to/unetbootin
chmod +x unetbootin-linux-583
./unetbootin-linux-583
```

Finally, fill in your password.

Answer (score 1):

Go in the software center and download wine. Then, download the windows version of unetbooting and run it with wine! Profit!

Comment: While this may work, it is more or less a workaround (and a pretty hacky one at that), rather than a solution. And a more in-depth answer on how to do this - seeing how bare wine is not exactly user-friendly - might be in order.